# Unexpected response from multi-part POST with requests.py

Tags: python, python-3.3, python-requests

I'm trying to POST a multi-part encoded form with requests in python 3.3

```
payload = {'name':'username','value':'m3ta','name':'password','value':'xxxxxxxx'}
files = {'c_file': open(saveimg, 'rb')}
sendc = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", data = payload, files = files)
response = sendc.text
print (response)
```

This is the post content from httpbin..

```
{
  "json": null,
  "files": {
    "c_file": "data:image/x-png;base64,(lots of binary data)},
  "form": {
    "value": "xxxxxxxx",
    "name": "password"
  },
  "headers": {
    "Heroku-Request-Id": "c101bf2e-d69a-4aab-ac15-b9005a7bcebe",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "identity, gzip, deflate, compress",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=c5b1e65ff0ac46029c88b9661f981534",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "X-Request-Id": "c101bf2e-d69a-4aab-ac15-b9005a7bcebe",
    "Content-Length": "12262",
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/1.2.3 CPython/3.3.2 Windows/7"
  },
  "origin": "81.107.44.15",
  "data": "",
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post",
  "args": {}
}
```

For some reason requests is not posting all the values in the "payload" dictionary. Where am I going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionaries can only hold *unique* keys; you have duplicate `'name'` and `'value'` keys.

Use a list of (key, value) pairs instead if you have duplicate parameters:

```
payload = [
    ('name', 'username'), ('value', 'm3ta'),
    ('name', 'password'), ('value', 'xxxxxxxx'),
]
```

Note that `httpbin.org` *also* uses a dictionary to represent posted values when it echos them back to you, so you won't see the change reflected there.

The POST body however *will* contain something along the lines of:

```
--36ae094926114bed8aa5518ba2e949a4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

username
--36ae094926114bed8aa5518ba2e949a4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="value"

m3ta
--36ae094926114bed8aa5518ba2e949a4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

password
--36ae094926114bed8aa5518ba2e949a4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="value"

xxxxxxxx
```

when you use a list of tuples like this.